# What does this lyric from Thriller refer to?

Tags: fandom, lyrics

The music video "Thriller" includes this lyric: (around 5:47 in [this video](https://youtu.be/sOnqjkJTMaA?t=347))

> They're out to get you
> There's demons closing in on every side (ooh)
> They will possess you
> Unless you change that number on your dial

This seems like an odd way for demons to behave.  Is this in reference to something?

(Context suggests that it might be a reference to a thriller movie?)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This is from the days before TV remote controls, when you actually had to get up out of your seat to change the channel (by turning a *dial* on front).

[image: A close up of TV dials: two big rotary knobs, one labelled UHF, the other VHF, both with number labels around them]

*Source: [Pixabay](https://pixabay.com/photos/vintage-tv-tv-ancient-old-1116587/), public domain.*

The lyrics immediately following the ones you quote are:

> Now is the time
> For you and I to cuddle close together, yeah
> All through the night
> I'll save you from the terror on the screen
> I'll make you see
>
> You know it's thriller, thriller night...

The narrator is not caught in a nightmare world, he's sitting on the sofa watching a horror movie marathon with his SO!

Comment: It does seem a bit schizophrenic... near the start of the video the couple is seen leaving a theater, suggesting a movie-going experience where "the dial" apparently reframes it to a tv-watching experience.

Comment: @AnthonyX I don’t think the song was written with the video in mind. That wasn't really a thing yet.

Comment: The phrase "don't touch that dial" is still used to tell people not to change the channel. It's a metaphorical dial, like dialing a telephone.

Comment: @Barmar first time I heard that about dialing a telephone. I guess the rotary is a kind of dial.

Comment: @KeithPayne: But you surely heard the word "dial" related to phones. "Dial me", "Speed dial", "Dial-up Internet" all come from the same original telephone dial.

Comment: @Spencer Why do you say that? The video and song came out just a month apart. It seems unlikely the video was conceived of and made in less than that time.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thriller_(song)#Release): _"Along with the rest of the album, "Thriller" was recorded over eight weeks in 1982...."Thriller" was the final single released from the album. It was not initially planned for release, as Jackson's record label, Epic, saw it as a novelty song...By mid-1983, sales of Thriller began to decline. Jackson...urged Yetnikoff and executive Larry Stessel to help conceive a plan to return the album to the top of the charts. Jackson's manager Frank DiLeo suggested releasing "Thriller", backed by a new music video."_

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- In the 1970's, the album was the basic unit of music production.   You had to have enough new material to play on tour.  Standalone singles existed but they were rare.   Videos were considered promotional and a cost center. (_Thriller_ changed that forever).

Comment: @Spencer Thanks, I quickly skimmed WP but missed that.

Comment: >> Standalone singles existed, but they were rare:  [umm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Billboard_number-one_singles_from_1950_to_1958), [no](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UK_Singles_Chart_number_ones_of_the_1960s)

Comment: @mcalex Do you have any numbers on how many were released off albums versus ones that weren't?

Comment: Though this type of TV was kind of behind the times even then.  Music videos like Thriller first made it big on networks like MTV and VH1, which are and always were *cable channels*, i.e. not something you could see on an old TV with VHF/UHF dials.  (General practice in the US was to attach a cable box which shows when the TV dial is set to channel 3 or 4 depending on your region.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Horror movie marathons, however, were more likely to appear on independent UHF channels. And my part of the US didn’t have cable until much later, so we had to rely on those same UHF channels for music videos.

Comment: @rodrigo yeah, of course re: "dial the phone." I mean that I never connected dialing a phone with turning a dial - except that the rotary on an old phone does turn.

Comment: @Spencer If you meant non-album singles then I misunderstood, but respectfully that position is even less correct.  Albums have long been essentially just collections of songs that the band/label hope to make as many singles out of as possible.   In any event, none of the first 10 songs in either of those links appear to be on albums.  I also did the 50s list for the UK: same result.

Comment: @mcalex First-release singles were a lot more prevalent in the 50s and 60s than in the 70s. That's why I specifically called out the 70s.  And no, lots of albums contain songs that would never sell as singles.  They released what they thought were the best songs for a second bite at the apple.

Comment: My point is just that both 33s and 45s have been as essential to the industry as each other since well, since 78s, at least up until CDs.  I've no idea what's going on now